# How to debug Django variables, specifically the session variable?

Tags: django, debugging, session

I have tried using pprint to debug the session variable but it gives me a memory object like <8hfw89h> or something. How can I see the keys inside the session variable or furthermore any other variable in Django?

{{ debug }} does not give me what I need either.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend the [django-debug-tool bar](http://justcramer.com/2008/09/07/django-debug-toolbar/), It also provides alot more other information on load times and such too.

Goodluck.